# How do I change a list item to an int?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of file names from which I extract a year, which then gets passed to a function to determine if it is a leap year. The files are spreadsheets with a sheet for each month. I then lookup a dictionary to retrieve the right number of days for each month. My functions work fine on their own, but if I feed the functions with the result of a regex search the functions bomb out because they are getting a list item. I thought I could simply change the type but that doesn't work. I have included a stripped down version of my code which illustrates the problem. Trying to change the type changes the type internally in the list, but the class remains a list, which causes the error.

```
# Python 3
import re

def isleapyear(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    return False


def numofdays(year, month):   
    if (month in months_lookup and month == "FEB" and isleapyear(year) is True):
        days = months_lookup.get(month)[1]
        return days
    else:
        days = months_lookup.get(month)[0]
        return days


months_lookup = {
        'JAN': (31,),
        'FEB': (28, 29),
        'MAR': (31,),
        'APR': (30,),
        'MAY': (31,),
        'JUN': (30,),
        'JUL': (31,),
        'AUG': (31,),
        'SEP': (30,),
        'OCT': (31,),
        'NOV': (30,),
        'DEC': (31,)}    


targetfiles = ['Testlog2009.xlsx', 'Testlog2010.xlsx', 'Testlog2011.xlsx', 'Testlog2008.xlsx']
targetfiles = sorted(targetfiles)
for tfile in targetfiles:
    for tmonth in months_lookup:
        # get year from filename
        pattern = '\d+'
        year = re.findall(pattern, tfile) # Returns a list type, but I need ant int.
        # check for leapyear and assign days to endRow
        days = numofdays(year, tmonth)
        print(days)
```

Comment: Why do you use `findall`? Can a filename contain more than one year? A fast, but dirty fix is `int(year[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

To get an item from a list, either use a loop, or use indexing. In this case, you only expect one value in the list returned by `re.findall` (more on this below), so you can just index with `year[0]`. That's still going to give you a string, albeit a numerical one. You can convert that to an integer with `int(year[0])`. Or you can combine everything together with `year = int(re.findall(...)[0])`.

But the indexing issue suggests that you probably don't want to be using `re.findall` in the first place. It is *designed* to find more than one result, if you only expect one, you should search for that directly. Instead of `re.findall(pattern, tfile)` to get the first result, use `re.search(pattern, tfile)` which will find the first part of the input string that matches the pattern. It returns a "match" object, and you can get the string that was matched by calling its `group` method:

```
year = int(re.search(pattern, tfile).group())
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` return a list of the part of `tfile` those matched with the pattern.
if you want just a number and you sure `tfile` has only one number you can get year like this:

```
year = int(re.findall(pattern, tfile)[0])
```